# Disable JSP Path Validation (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

[image]

There are a few errors like this that show up in my workspace. I looked up the JSP Validation segment under Preferences, but could not find which one disables this. I can set everything to Warning or Ignore. But I would like to keep the other validations in and only remove this one.  Can you please let me know which one to disable for this? Thanks.

Comment: What's the value in the Type column?

Comment: @nitind Sorry about the delay. It says `Web Resource Problem`.

Comment: That's coming from some other plug-in, likely https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources .